# I want to add a distance between my room menu from my sub-menu

Tags: javascript, html, css

I wanted to create a distance between my list items in my sub-menus and adding a padding doesn't seem to work.

Example:

Room  Lighting  Accessories  Contact  About Us
Living room
Dining room
Home office or Study
Bedroom

It suppose to look like this,

Room Lighting Accessories Contact About Us

Living room
             <----- padding------>
Dining room

Home office or Study

Bedroom

I don't have a very good English but i hope you guys get what i mean. Thank you so much for the help.

```js
var flag;
myFunction();

function myFunction() {

  var x = document.getElementById("myTopnav");
  var y = document.getElementById("mySubnav");

  if (x.className === "topnav") {

    x.className += " responsive";
    if (flag === 1) {
      y.className += " responsive";
    }

  } else {


    if (x.className === "topnav responsive" && y.className === "subnav responsive") {
      flag = 1;
    } else if (x.className === "topnav responsive" && y.className !== "subnav responsive") {
      flag = 0;
    } else {

      y.className = "subnav";
    }

    x.className = "topnav";
    y.className = "subnav";
  }

}

function subnavFunction() {
  var y = document.getElementById("mySubnav");
  var x = document.getElementById("myTopnav");
  if (y.className === "subnav") {

    y.className += " responsive";

  } else {
    y.className = "subnav";
  }

}
```

```css
html,
body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 20px;
  height: 100%;
}

header h1 {
  margin: 0;
  display: inline;
}

header ul {
  margin: 0;
  list-style-type: none;
  padding-left: 0px;
}

header ul li a {
  display: inline;
  padding-right: 20px;
  font-size: 18px;
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #444;
  transition: color 170ms ease-in-out, background-color 170ms ease-in-out;
}

header ul h1 a {
  padding-right: 20px;
  text-decoration: none;
  display: block;
  font-weight: normal;
  color: #444;
}


/* mouse over link */

header ul li a:hover {
  color: #999;
  text-decoration: none;
}


/* selected link */

header ul li a:active {
  color: #555;
  text-decoration: none;
}

.TitleHeader {
  color: #444;
  text-align: center;
  padding-top: 150px;
  font-family: "Times New Roman";
}

.footer {
  text-decoration: none;
}

.topnav header ul li a {
  display: inline;
  padding-bottom: 20px;
}

.topnav .icon {
  position: absolute;
  display: none;
  right: 10px;
  top: 10px;
  color: #555;
}

.wrapper {
  min-height: 100%;
  margin-bottom: -50px;
}

.footer,
.push {
  height: 50px;
  text-align: center;
  font-family: "Times New Roman";
}

@media screen and (max-width: 699px) {
  .topnav ul li a {
    display: none;
    padding: 10px;
  }
  .topnav .icon {
    display: inline;
    position: absolute;
    top: 45px;
    right: 50px;
    padding-bottom: 5px;
    padding-left: 5px;
    padding-right: 5px;
    padding-top: 5px;
  }
  .topnav.responsive .subnav .subIcon {
    display: inline-block;
    position: absolute;
    top: 75px;
    left: 100px;
  }
  header ul h1 a {
    display: block;
    text-align: center;
    -webkit-animation: fadein 1s;
  }
  @keyframes fadein {
    from {
      opacity: 0;
    }
    to {
      opacity: 1;
    }
  }
}

@media screen and (max-width: 699px) {
  .topnav.responsive ul li a {
    float: none;
    display: inline-block;
    text-align: left;
    padding-left: 10px;
  }
  a.subIcon {
    margin-left: 30px;
  }
  .subnav.responsive .subIcon {
    transform: rotate(90deg);
    transition: all .25s ease-out;
  }
  .subnav .subIcon {
    transition: all .25s ease-out;
  }
  .topnav .subnav.responsive ul li a {
    display: block;
  }
  .topnav .subnav.responsive ul {
    padding-left: 10px;
  }
  .topnav .subnav ul li a {
    display: none;
  }
}

@media screen and (min-width: 700px) {
  .topnav ul li {
    display: none;
    display: inline-block;
    -webkit-animation: fadein 1s;
    display: visible;
  }
  header ul h1 a {
    display: inline;
  }
  .topnav .icon {
    display: none;
  }
  .subnav .subIcon {
    display: none;
  }
  .subnav ul li {
    display: none;
  }
  .room:hover .subnav ul li {
    display: inline;
  }
  .subnav ul {
    position: absolute;
    display: inline;
    float: left;
  }
  .subnav ul li a {
    padding-top: 10px;
    padding: 10px 20px;
  }
}

.GreyText {
  color: #777;
}
```

```html
<!doctype html>
<html>

<head>

  <title> Home </title>

  <link href="mainCSS.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">

  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">

</head>

<body>

  <div class="wrapper">
    <header>

      <div class="topnav" id="myTopnav">
        <!-- Whole navigation menu -->
        <ul>

          <h1 class="first"><a href="MyWebsiteCSS.html">UrbanAero</a></h1>
          <li class="room"><a href="#">Rooms</a>
            <div class="subnav" id="mySubnav">
              <ul class="boi">
                <li><a href="#">Living room</a></li><br>
                <li><a href="#">Dining room</a></li><br>
                <li><a href="#">Home office and Study</a></li><br>
                <li><a href="#">Bedroom</a></li>
                <a href="javascript:void(0);" class="subIcon" onclick="subnavFunction();"><i class="fa fa-caret-down" aria-hidden="true"></i></a>
              </ul>
            </div>
          </li>

          <li><a href="#">lighting</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Accessories</a></li>
          <li><a class="GreyText" href="ContactCSS.html">Contact</a></li>
          <li><a class="GreyText" href="AboutCSS.html">About Us</a></li>
          <li>
            <a href="javascript:void(0);" class="icon" onclick="myFunction()"></li>
          <li><i class="fa fa-bars"></i></a>
          </li>

        </ul>

      </div>
    </header>




    <div class="push">

    </div>

  </div>

  <footer class="footer">&#0169;UrbanAero</footer>

</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When it comes to margins and padding, browsers treat inline elements differently. You can add space to the left and right on an inline element, but you cannot add height to the top or bottom padding or margin of an inline element.

In order to make the padding work, change your anchors to inline-block:

```
header ul li a{
  display: inline-block;
}
```

**Updated code**

```js
var flag;
myFunction();

function myFunction() {

  var x = document.getElementById("myTopnav");
  var y = document.getElementById("mySubnav");

  if (x.className === "topnav") {

    x.className += " responsive";
    if (flag === 1) {
      y.className += " responsive";
    }

  } else {


    if (x.className === "topnav responsive" && y.className === "subnav responsive") {
      flag = 1;
    } else if (x.className === "topnav responsive" && y.className !== "subnav responsive") {
      flag = 0;
    } else {

      y.className = "subnav";
    }

    x.className = "topnav";
    y.className = "subnav";
  }

}

function subnavFunction() {
  var y = document.getElementById("mySubnav");
  var x = document.getElementById("myTopnav");
  if (y.className === "subnav") {

    y.className += " responsive";

  } else {
    y.className = "subnav";
  }

}
```

```css
html,
body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 20px;
  height: 100%;
}

header h1 {
  margin: 0;
  display: inline;
}

header ul {
  margin: 0;
  list-style-type: none;
  padding-left: 0px;
}

header ul li a {
  display: inline-block;
  padding-right: 20px;
  font-size: 18px;
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #444;
  transition: color 170ms ease-in-out, background-color 170ms ease-in-out;
}

header ul h1 a {
  padding-right: 20px;
  text-decoration: none;
  display: block;
  font-weight: normal;
  color: #444;
}


/* mouse over link */

header ul li a:hover {
  color: #999;
  text-decoration: none;
}


/* selected link */

header ul li a:active {
  color: #555;
  text-decoration: none;
}

.TitleHeader {
  color: #444;
  text-align: center;
  padding-top: 150px;
  font-family: "Times New Roman";
}

.footer {
  text-decoration: none;
}

.topnav header ul li a {
  display: inline;
  padding-bottom: 20px;
}

.topnav .icon {
  position: absolute;
  display: none;
  right: 10px;
  top: 10px;
  color: #555;
}

.wrapper {
  min-height: 100%;
  margin-bottom: -50px;
}

.footer,
.push {
  height: 50px;
  text-align: center;
  font-family: "Times New Roman";
}

@media screen and (max-width: 699px) {
  .topnav ul li a {
    display: none;
    padding: 10px;
  }
  .topnav .icon {
    display: inline;
    position: absolute;
    top: 45px;
    right: 50px;
    padding-bottom: 5px;
    padding-left: 5px;
    padding-right: 5px;
    padding-top: 5px;
  }
  .topnav.responsive .subnav .subIcon {
    display: inline-block;
    position: absolute;
    top: 75px;
    left: 100px;
  }
  header ul h1 a {
    display: block;
    text-align: center;
    -webkit-animation: fadein 1s;
  }
  @keyframes fadein {
    from {
      opacity: 0;
    }
    to {
      opacity: 1;
    }
  }
}

@media screen and (max-width: 699px) {
  .topnav.responsive ul li a {
    float: none;
    display: inline-block;
    text-align: left;
    padding-left: 10px;
  }
  a.subIcon {
    margin-left: 30px;
  }
  .subnav.responsive .subIcon {
    transform: rotate(90deg);
    transition: all .25s ease-out;
  }
  .subnav .subIcon {
    transition: all .25s ease-out;
  }
  .topnav .subnav.responsive ul li a {
    display: block;
  }
  .topnav .subnav.responsive ul {
    padding-left: 10px;
  }
  .topnav .subnav ul li a {
    display: none;
  }
}

@media screen and (min-width: 700px) {
  .topnav ul li {
    display: none;
    display: inline-block;
    -webkit-animation: fadein 1s;
    display: visible;
  }
  header ul h1 a {
    display: inline;
  }
  .topnav .icon {
    display: none;
  }
  .subnav .subIcon {
    display: none;
  }
  .subnav ul li {
    display: none;
  }
  .room:hover .subnav ul li {
    display: inline;
  }
  .subnav ul {
    position: absolute;
    display: inline;
    float: left;
  }
  .subnav ul li a {
    padding-top: 10px;
    padding: 10px 20px;
  }
}

.GreyText {
  color: #777;
}
```

```html
<!doctype html>
<html>

<head>

  <title> Home </title>

  <link href="mainCSS.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">

  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">

</head>

<body>

  <div class="wrapper">
    <header>

      <div class="topnav" id="myTopnav">
        <!-- Whole navigation menu -->
        <ul>

          <h1 class="first"><a href="MyWebsiteCSS.html">UrbanAero</a></h1>
          <li class="room"><a href="#">Rooms</a>
            <div class="subnav" id="mySubnav">
              <ul class="boi">
                <li><a href="#">Living room</a></li><br>
                <li><a href="#">Dining room</a></li><br>
                <li><a href="#">Home office and Study</a></li><br>
                <li><a href="#">Bedroom</a></li>
                <a href="javascript:void(0);" class="subIcon" onclick="subnavFunction();"><i class="fa fa-caret-down" aria-hidden="true"></i></a>
              </ul>
            </div>
          </li>

          <li><a href="#">lighting</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Accessories</a></li>
          <li><a class="GreyText" href="ContactCSS.html">Contact</a></li>
          <li><a class="GreyText" href="AboutCSS.html">About Us</a></li>
          <li>
            <a href="javascript:void(0);" class="icon" onclick="myFunction()"></li>
          <li><i class="fa fa-bars"></i></a>
          </li>

        </ul>

      </div>
    </header>




    <div class="push">

    </div>

  </div>

  <footer class="footer">&#0169;UrbanAero</footer>

</body>

</html>
```